# String memory allocation and string pool concepts

Tags: java, string, memory-management, string-pool

What is the difference between these two assignments, in terms of memory allocation and String pools.

```
String b = "sunil" + "khokhar";
```

and

```
String a = "sunil";
String b = a + "khokhar";
```

Comment: What do you think would happen?  How do you think the compiler and the string pool would be different?  Have you considered what difference using `final` might make?

Comment: what does it matter. what is your actual requirement for which you want to use the above approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String b = "sunil" + "khokhar";
```

both `"sunil"` and `"khokar"` will be concatenated and the value of `b` will be resolved during compile-time.  So, `"sunilkhokhar` will be present in the *String constant pool*.
and

```
String a = "sunil";
String b = a + "khokhar";
```

`"sunil"` and `"khokar"` will be compile time constants (and be added to the String pool).
But `b = a+"khokhar"` will be done using `StringBuilder` and will occur at runtime.
So, `b` will be present in *heap* and not in the *String constant pool*.

Answer (score 0):

String is a final class every time you user "+" and "=" new object will be created. For Variable assignments, if value already exists in pool then reference will be returned along with Object.

Comment: Not every time. No, only when you are using *a reference which is not final during concatenation*. So, `a + "khokhar"` will be resolved during compile time if `a` is *final*.

Comment: I think in case of String b="sunil"+"khokhar" only one object is created having value "sunilkhokhar" and one entry in string pool which refer this object.

Comment: and In case of                                                String a = "sunil";
String b = a + "khokhar"; two object is created and 2 reference in.   @TheLostMind correct me if a am wrong

Comment: @SunilKhokhar - 3 String objects. "sunil" and "khokhar" will be in *String constants pool* and "sunilkhokhar" will be on heap. So, totally 3.